# Dynamically generating XML Schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xerces2-j

I am trying to dynamically generate XML schema using Xerces-J and getting the following error, appreciate any help regarding it.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbfac.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

Element schema = doc.createElement("xs:schema");           
schema.setAttribute("xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
doc.appendChild(schema);

Element e = doc.createElement("xs:element");            
e.setAttribute("name", "test");
e.setAttribute("type", "xs:string");

schema.appendChild(e);

TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

//create string from xml tree
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

trans.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = sw.toString();

System.out.println(xmlString);

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

Schema schema1 = schemaFactory.newSchema(source);

Output is

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'xs:schema' must be from 
the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.

Answer (score 2):

When building a DOM, you don't specify namespaces as attributes. Instead, use the version of `createElement()` that takes two parameters: the first is the namespace URI, the second is the element's qualified name.

Note also that the prefix of a qualified name will automatically be matched to the namespace URI. If you want, you could eliminate the prefix altogether, and the serializer will do the right thing (either creating an `xmlns` attribute without prefix, or generating a prefix).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the code as per your recommendation to  Element                                     schema = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xs:schema");                                                       and I am getting the following error                                 s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'schema' is invalid.  Element 'xs:element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Comment: @user1959200 - did you also update the line where you create the `element` element?

Comment: Changing setElement to setElementNS and setAttribute to setAttributeNS worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and found the [Apache Commons XMLSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema/index.html)